# New Command For Inline Code

Tags: macros, listings

I am using the `listings` package to enter large blocks of code into my document, however I am trying to write a custom command that uses my current settings to do inline code.  For example I want to be able to say something like:

To create a new function in `Python` that took two arguments you would use

```
\inlinecode{def myFunction(x, y):}
```

**EDIT:** Here are is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}#1\end{lstlisting}}

% Custom Python Syntax
\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green},
    keywordstyle=\color{Cerulean},
    frame=L,
    language=python,
    morekeywords={True, False},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{Mulberry},
    tabsize=3,
}

% Color Numbers
\lstset
{
    literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{Orange}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{Orange}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{Orange}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{Orange}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{Orange}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{Orange}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{Orange}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{Orange}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{Orange}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{Orange}9}}}1
}

\begin{document}
    To create a new function in Python that took two arguments you would use \inlinecode{def myFunction(x, y):}
\end{document}
```

and my new command is:

```
\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}#1\end{lstlisting}}
```

however I keep getting this error:

[image: Console Output]

I have hardly any experience writing custom commands so I assume that's where my problem is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The verbatim content of `#1` is to blame, in my point of view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro for inputting inline code is `\lstinline[option]{<code}` Hence use  `\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

% Custom Python Syntax
\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green},
    keywordstyle=\color{Cerulean},
    frame=L,
    language=python,
    morekeywords={True, False},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{Mulberry},
    tabsize=3,
}

% Color Numbers
\lstset
{
    literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{Orange}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{Orange}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{Orange}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{Orange}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{Orange}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{Orange}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{Orange}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{Orange}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{Orange}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{Orange}9}}}1
}

\begin{document}
    To create a new function in Python that took two arguments you would use \inlinecode{def myFunction(x, y):}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But why not use `\lstinline` directly? Or you can simply do `\newcommand{\inlinecode}{\lstinline}` as suggested by Werner.

Comment: In my opinion it would be *far* better to use `\newcommand{\inlinecode}{\lstinline}`. This allows you to use `\inlinecode{...}` or `\inlinecode!...!` or `\inlinecode[<opts>]{...}`...

Comment: @Werner Yes, this is just an attempt to follow OP's way. I will add a note. Thanks

Comment: I think defining a custom command is fine, sometimes you want to be able to influence the way code looks, add a compat mode to your document (imagine somebody doesn't have listings package, you can define a switch to fall back to regular ttstyle, and so on).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\inlinecode}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize, prebreak=]}

% Custom Python Syntax
\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green},
    keywordstyle=\color{Cerulean},
    frame=L,
    language=python,
    morekeywords={True, False},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{Mulberry},
    tabsize=3,
}

% Color Numbers
\lstset
{
    literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{Orange}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{Orange}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{Orange}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{Orange}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{Orange}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{Orange}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{Orange}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{Orange}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{Orange}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{Orange}9}}}1
}

\begin{document}
    To create a new function in Python that took two arguments you would use \inlinecode{def myFunction(x, y):}
\end{document}
```