# New command for mathmode + tikzcd?

Tags: environments, tikz-cd

I wanted to do something that enables me to write
    `\tikzdiagram{ stuff }`
or something like 
    `\tik stuff \zcd` instead of having to write 
    `\[\begin{tikzcd} stuff \end{tikzcd}\]`
every time I want a diagram.

I tried things like `\newcommand{\tikd}[1]{\[\begin{tikzcd}#1\end{tikzcd}\]}` but that did not work very well.

I'm sure this must be a common desire, but I couldn't find any information out there (but maybe someone who is better knowing what words to search for will).

I also thought this could be related: [New Command For Inline Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239028/new-command-for-inline-code)

**Edit:** It seems like it is indeed drawing a diagram since `\tikd{a\ar{r}}` is giving the "no shape" error, but that the & sign is not working out since it gets a "wrong catcode" error.

**Edit2:** Following Piet's suggestion, I settled for the following:

```
\newcommand{\tik}{\[\begin{tikzcd}}
\newcommand\zcd{\end{tikzcd}\]}
```

Comment: Try newenvironment rather than newcommand.

Comment: The tikzcd environment changes the catcode of `&`, so you cannot pick up the contents of the environment and pass it around.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this: you save just a few keys at the expense of markup. If you decide that a diagram should have a number, you'll need `\begin{equation}` and the shorthand will not work.

Comment: @egreg But that can be done with another shorthand.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Is it worth the trouble? And another one if you want the diagram in a `gather` and so on?

Comment: It is for the OP to decide whether it is worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\tik}{\[\begin{tikzcd}}
\newcommand\zcd{\end{tikzcd}\]}

\tik a & b \\ c & d \zcd
```

Comment: Works quite well, it seems! Wonder why my attempt at the same thing didn't work...

Comment: Don't use a definition that needs `#1`.